# C# using HttpWebRequest Post method doesn't work

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Hey I'm trying to figure out using HttpWebRequest to do a Post request to a login page, say yahoo mail, and examine the returned page source.

But using my Post method I still got the login page.

Here is my method:

```
public static string GetResponse(string sURL, ref CookieContainer cookies, string sParameters)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36";
        httpRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        httpRequest.Method = "Post";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpRequest.ContentLength = sParameters.Length;
        httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;            

        using (Stream stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sParameters), 0, sParameters.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

        string sResponse;
        using (Stream stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(936));
            sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return sResponse;
    }
```

The code to call the method is:

```
        string sParameter = ".tries=1&.src=ym&.md5=&.hash=&.js=&.last=&promo=&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.bypass=&.partner=&.u=eip09319532h1&.v=0&.challenge=3QjvX9eEFtJRrABhZp9kgS9IT.VO&.yplus=&.emailCode=&pkg=&stepid=&.ev=&hasMsgr=0&.chkP=Y&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&.pd=ym_ver%3D0%26c%3D%26ivt%3D%26sg%3D&.ws=1&.cp=0&nr=0&pad=3&aad=3&login=username%40yahoo.com&passwd=xxxxx&.persistent=&.save=&passwd_raw=";
        System.Net.CookieContainer coookies = null ;
        string sResponse;

        sResponse = GetResponse(sUrl, ref coookies, sParameter);
```

The string sParameter was obtained by examining the data posted to the server in Firefox's Firebug plugin. But in the parameters I posted above, I masked my user id and password.

I wanted to re-use the session so I passed a CookieContainer object as reference to the method.

It compiles and runs, but the page returned to me is not logged-in status.

I have read several similar questions on stackoverflow, but still can't make my method work. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the verb/method be "POST", not "Post"?

Comment: Why are you using a `ref` parameter for your cookieContainer? Did you intend to modify the reference (*not* the object referred to) so that it is changed at the caller site of this function? I'll bet you don't need to do that.

Comment: Take a read here to learn more about what `ref` actually means and why it probably doesn't do what you think it does. http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: ... next step? Download/Open Fiddler2, issue the request from the browser... issue the request from your program... spot the difference. If you're still in doubt, post the evidence here.